# randomize scattering geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I'm trying to scatter a collection of buildings ontop scattered cubes across a plane. The issue im having is that every cube is using the same points i think? So the scattering becomes very repetitive. Any one knows how I could fix that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: realize cube instances.